# FLUTTER::::if the complaintAcceptedDate is null then dont show both containers otherwise display both ....how is it possible

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
      Container(
                margin:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 2 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                child: Text(
                  'Complaint AcceptedDate',
                  style: AppStyles.pageDetailsCommonText
                      .copyWith(color: AppColors.colorDarkGrey),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 1 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                child: Text(
                  '${model.historyInfo[index].complaintAcceptedDate}',
                  style: AppStyles.pageDetailsCommonText
                      .copyWith(color: AppColors.colorBlack),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: can you share where your code has gone wrong? and what the problem is? thanks!

Comment: @DEV It is possible just tell me is it Column or Row which contain both Container. Added condition  outside column or row like if it is null don't show both container

Comment: bro, it's inside the column

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Visibility` widget to easily manage this case.

Wrap your `Container` widgets with `Visiblity` widget & check for `null`.

It should look something like this:

```
      Visibility(
        visible: model.historyInfo[index].complaintAcceptedDate != null,
        child: Container(
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 2 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
            child: Text(
              'Complaint AcceptedDate',
              style: AppStyles.pageDetailsCommonText
                  .copyWith(color: AppColors.colorDarkGrey),
            ),
          ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: model.historyInfo[index].complaintAcceptedDate != null,
          child:  Container(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 1 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
            child: Text(
              '${model.historyInfo[index].complaintAcceptedDate}',
              style: AppStyles.pageDetailsCommonText
                  .copyWith(color: AppColors.colorBlack),
            ),
          ),
          ),
```

Comment: Welcome buddy, if this answer was helpful, please mark this as accepted and upvote this answer so that others can understand that this is the correct answer.